# Product images are serving from different path in Frontend and Backend

Tags: cache, product-images, product-view, media

Frontend Product images are serving from this [path1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img24.jpg) :

```
media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/i/m/img24.jpg
```

Backend Product images are serving from this [path2](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/media/catalog/product/i/m/img24.jpg)

```
media/catalog/product/i/m/img24.jpg
```

why same images stored in different path.

I think Backend images are serving from proper path, I want frontend images also should serve from same path.

**Edit**

why we need is lot of product images are not indexed by google. only few images are indexed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because magento frontend is use `catalog media cache` which means media will be come from cache folder (**This is the best way to speed up your website**).

But as you said you want the main image then i will say to try this code

```
 <?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage()); ?>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: can you please give me file path and what code need to change ?

Comment: that depends on your need. The code i gave is to get the original file url.. But now you need to implement it on your code. as i dont know your codes. :)

Comment: thnaks , generally in default magento in what file path i have to chnage code ?

Comment: is i need to check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207886/magento-product-images-full-url-path-instead-of-cached?newreg=e834df4722654cee8108084c45b64407

Comment: Yes you can follow that

Comment: in the default `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/image.php` file , where i need to add this code as suggested in that link:

`echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage());`

Comment: according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22207886/magento-product-images-full-url-path-instead-of-cached?newreg=e834df4722654cee8108084c45b64407) , i added code `echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $_product->getSmallImage());`in end of the file as like this :  http://pastebin.com/a6qEnDBV after that no images loaded in site.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: i added your code at end of the this file :`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/image.php file` but it did't worked for me.
please tell me where i need to your code.

Comment: Where you need to show your image like in `app/design/frontend/youtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` page.

Comment: i added like this : http://pasted.co/51e46d4d , all i need is 

frontend product view image path should come from `media/catalog/product/i/m/img24.jpg`

Comment: No you need to go to `app/design/frontend/youtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` then view the code you can find the <image src="" /> tag where the image is being echo.. there you need to replace my code

Comment: according to your update code, i updated as here : http://pasted.co/616b8fbb

Comment: i will check it ......

Comment: again you are doing wrong.. I am saying to add the code `app/design/frontend/youtheme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` like for rwd list page this is the list.phtml code http://pasted.co/2b90eb08

Comment: i updated your code, please  check line number 69 here : http://pasted.co/3570fef1 ,if wrong correct me.

Comment: replace `<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, $alt_img)->resize($setting->getProductsGrid_Width(225), $setting->getProductsGrid_Height()); ?>` with my code

Comment: sory ,still same result : [link](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000.html)

Comment: Man! Please try to debug.. You need to understand where you need to put code.. You can take help by turning on template path hints...

Comment: pls check [link1](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/electronics/microsoft-natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000.html?tp=1&code=toy)

is i need to add in view.phtml ? because i need result in product view page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38673/discussion-between-asish-hira-and-user9999).

Comment: please check when you are free.

Comment: Hello! What happening?? Did you solved that???

Comment: come on chat! Lets discuss on there